# What is the correct way to re-export this type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a pure functional react component in typescript like this:

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';

export default ({
  onClick,
}: {
  onClick: (evt: MouseEvent) => void,
}) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>
    Hello world
  </div>
);
```

This naturally gives an error because `MouseEvent` is a private name but is also a part of the signature for my functional component. So I go to re-export:

```
export { MouseEvent };
```

Which does not fix the error. I'm guessing because while there's a type 'MouseEvent' from the React typings there's also a `MouseEvent` constructor and the compiler is disambiguating to the latter. So then I try

```
export { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

Which also does not fix the error. In a bit of desperation and following an old github thread I also tried

```
export * from 'react';
```

How do I fix this? (using tsc 3.6.3 if that matters)

Comment: What error are you getting? I do this all the time and never have to re-export something from React.

Comment: Did you try import React, { MouseEvent as MEvent } from 'react';
And use it

Comment: @rickdenhaan default export using private name 'MouseEvent'.

Comment: @Oleg aliasing the import fixed it. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with alias:

```
   import React, { MouseEvent as MEvent } from 'react';
```

The compiler will then no longer throw the private name error and you don't have to re-export the name.